# If I get a new PC will I still be able to access shared games?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I'll be changing my PC, if I change it will I still be able to have all of my shared games?

Comment: Are you the owner or the person being shared with?

Comment: Person being shared with.

Answer (score 9):

To have access to a steam library, both the PC you are using and the account you are using must have been given access to the library.

Taken from the Steam family guide:

> Is there a limit to the number of devices or friends I can authorize
>   to share my Library?
>
> Yes. You may authorize Family Library Sharing on
>   up to 10 devices at a given time, and for up to 5 accounts that may
>   then use your game library on any of your authorized computers.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing)

So, if you get a new PC or do a significant upgrade on it (E.g. change your operating system version from Windows 8 to 10 (Thanks to  [Khale_Kitha](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/139243/khale-kitha) for the info)), you need your device to be authorised, by the sharer account owner, before you can access those games again.

The reason I know this, I've had this issue with my friends and had to re-authorise their new PCs to access my library, whilst removing their old PC. This was even with their account already being authorised to access my games.

Comment: This also occurs when you upgrade OS's, sometimes, as I found out a few months ago.  My wife and I had to re-auth each other because she could see my library, but I could not see hers.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha, actually really important note - Draken, add this to answer. After Win8 -> Win10 upgrade I had to reauthorize all machines in family.

Comment: Updated as requested @Sanctus